# Можно ли разграничить доступ к определенным диапозонам? Google таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-drive, права-доступа

Можно ли  сделать так, чтобы определенные столбцы или строки не были видны определенным пользователем?

Answer (score 2):

Такой возможности не предусмотрено. Для разделения доступа к данным используйте несколько Таблиц.

Comment: Тогда появляется проблема эргономичного ввода данных в первоисточник.
Хотелось бы одной группе пользователей давать просматривать и редактировать только исходные данные.
Другой группе - редактировать исходные данные и результат их обсчета (без переключений между двумя таблицами, при большом количестве данных неудобно). Есть какое-то эргономичное решение?

Comment: Создал отдельный вопрос.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720324/google-spreadshets-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0