# Разграничение доступа к исходным данным и результатам их обсчета в Таблицах Google

Tags: google-spreadsheet, права, доступ

Хочется одной группе пользователей давать просматривать и редактировать только исходные данные.

Другой группе - редактировать исходные данные и результат их обсчета (без переключений между двумя таблицами, при большом количестве данных неудобно).

Есть какое-то секьюрное и эргономичное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Такой возможности нет.

Считаю закономерным ожидать возможности запрета просмотра части данных Таблицы. Если бы не одно "но".

Доступ предоставляется на базовый элемент системы - файл. Это означает, что все внутренние права не могут быть более мягкими, нежели разрешения на базовый элемент. Типы доступа на файлы всем известны:

- Нет
- Разрешено видеть
- Разрешено комментировать
- Разрешено редактировать
- Владелец

Представим ситуацию, при которой будет произведено усиление ограничений внутри файла. Как это отразится на внешних правах? Как пользователь может узнать, что в этом документе он Гендельф, а в другом Бесправный Пони? Как должна вести себя система по отношению к связанным файлам? К импорту и экспорту? Как система должна добавлять/удалять права в отношении базового элемента?

Вопросов так много, что решить их непредставляется возможным. По крайней мере не в той системе, которая существует. Не стоит рассчитывать на запрет просмотра части данных, какими бы они ни были.

Самое интересное, что следующий код "утянет" все данные из Таблицы, если даже у вас доступ только на просмотр с запретом на скачивание.

```
function reveal_(fromId, toId) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(toId);
  var shets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fromId).getSheets().forEach(function(s) {
    var ns = spreadsheet.insertSheet();
    var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
    ns.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  });
}
```

С таким же успехом можно получить формулы, форматирование, уловное форматирование и проверку данных.

### Дополнительно

#### Скрипты

Если честно, то не знаю общей практики, но я использую следующий вариант разграничения прав. Публикуется веб-апп скрипт от имени владельца/редактора Таблицы, который может вносить (или оображать) только определенные данные. Тогда можно разграничить пользователей по доступу к функциям веб-аппа, а редакторы и владелец будут редактировать данные в нормальном режиме.
Основное преимущество в том, что можно задать направление процесса и отображать приложение на мобильном.

Comment: Да, это понятно, спасибо.
Если бы была возможность вносить данные в первоисточник, не переключаясь в него, тоже было бы нормальным вариантом. Может это возможно с помощью какого-то API-костыля? Еще лучше простыми средствами, но вроде бы нет вариантов. То есть тянем данные из исходной таблицы в обработку. Если вносим в обработку изменения (ну или на худой конец в соседний с ними пустой столбец) - скрипт вносит новую цифру в исходник.

Comment: @konst54, добавил дополнительно. Пользователям с низкими правами можно вообще не открывать Таблицу.